# Generate multiple plots in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I want to make automatic report in R Markdown with multiple similar plots. I have a list which contains some similar data frames. I need a separate plot in output for each data frame. The main problem is that I need to reproduce this report with different conditions and length of the list can be different. I tried this solution:

```
for (i in 1:length(list.of.dfs)) {
plot(list.of.dfs[[i]])
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: please provide more details or noone can help you: what was the error message? did you load the data-frames before? did it show any output? what is the code of the entire chunk where the command is???

Comment: *How* didn't it work? My guess is that you wound up with one plot --- the last one --- instead of the series or grid of plots you wanted. If that's right, then you'll need either to make a function to call in your `for` loop that outputs or saves each plot, or run something like `par(mfcol=c(2, length(list.of.dfs)/2))` right before your `for` loop and then `dev.off()` afterwards to give the plots places to go.

Comment: Everybody sorry. I can't make multiple plots only with function `d3heatmap()`.  I thought that this problem is general for any plot.

Answer (score 2):

(Can't post graphics in comments…not necessarily suggesting this is an answer)

The following:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
mtcars_list <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
for (i in seq_along(mtcars_list)) {
  plot(mtcars_list[[i]], main=i)
}
```
````

produces:

[image]

Please check your data and/or provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I used this inbuilt *R* function to plot 4 graphs in 2 rows and 2 cols.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

You can read more about the function here: http://rfunction.com/archives/1538